# Как на nginx настроить правила 301 редиректа для .html .htm страниц?

Tags: nginx, redirect

Есть сервер на `nginx`.
Мне необходимо настроить 301 редирект со страниц example.com/about.html на example.com/about/,
example.com/about.htm на example.com/about/ и т.д., чтобы исключить дубли и ошибочные страницы.

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name ${VIRTUAL_HOST};

    # redirect all http to https
    return 301 https://$server_name$request_uri;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте так:

```
if ($request_uri ~ "^(.*)\.(?:php|html|htm)") {
   return 301 $1;
}
```

Comment: с `html` и `htm` - да, но убивает админку по адресу example.com/wp-admin и у example.com/index.php обрезает расширение и  возвращает страницу ошибки 404 с адресной строкой example.com/index

Comment: `if ($request_uri ~* "^(.*/)index\.(html|php)$") { return 301 $1; }` вот так решает проблемы выше, но с `html` и `htm` теперь уже не работает..

Comment: А если так:
сначала для index.php:
 if ($request_uri ~ "^(.*)index\.(?:php|html|htm)") { return 301 $1; }
ниже еще: 
 if($request_uri ~ "^(?!wp-admin|wp-login)(.*)\.(?:php|html|htm)") { return 301 $1/ ; }

Comment: получаю `502 Bad Gateway`